# Entity Framework error when searching a set for a bool value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using LINQ to query on a set created using EF Code First.

The code below produces an ArgumentException with the message "DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type."

```
var result = set.Any(item => item.val);

// where set is a DBSet<mytype> and mytype.val is a bool.
```

Jacob

---

Added after comments:

The original query is:

```
var set = table.where(item => DateTime.Now() < item.date + item.interval);

// where .date is a DateTime and .interval is a Timespan
```

Jacob

Comment: The problem may be how you define `set`; you just aren't seeing it until you actually execute it by calling `.Any()`.  Does `set` have a `Where` clause?  Ususally the problem is a date filter that EF can't directly translate to SQL.

Comment: @D Stanley
Yes there is a date filter. Any suggestion how to resolve it?

Comment: I suggest you post the query that includes the filter.

Comment: it is:

    var set = table.where(item => DateTime.Now() < item.date + item.interval);

    // where .date is a DateTime and .interval is a Timespan

Comment: Please add it to your question to get better formatting.

Comment: If you google the error message the first result gives you a likely answer.